# Are there any Apps to run Kodak ESP 3250?

Tags: drivers, printing

All I can find is for Windows and Mac

Answer (score 1):

When adding new printer use [this PPD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/) file.

Also you can try with this printer file at [openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Kodak/Kodak-ESP_3250).

To add printer, go to `System` -> `Administration` -> `Printing` and click `Add`.

For using the printer, you simple use graphical, scanning and office apps as usual like openOffice, Gimp, Simple scan, etc...

good luck.